# Location of web parts in use

Tags: web-part, migration

After running preupgrade check, I found a few instances of some web parts I'd like to further investigate.  These are 3rd party web parts that I'd like to know where they are actually being used.

For example, Id = f9699ea3-fbf1-9ff7-99f6-17c856b8e3e9, Type = CorasWSC.Site.WorkSpace.Viewer, Reference = 79, Status = Installed

It's listed as being used in 79 locations.  Is there a program (codeplex perhaps?), stsadm, or powershell command that could find the 79 site location URLs where this is being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stsadm command enumallwebs can be used with the -includewebparts option to work out in which sites the web parts are being referenced.

Comment: That was it, I forgot about all the switches in enumallwebs which aren't documented at all on the stsadm index page, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789634(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Eric,

It looks like you already worked a solution, but I'll also offer this up. Phil Childs has some documented PowerShell over on his blog that will actually identify the specific page that contains a given web part. I've needed to dig down to that level a few times during upgrade work; it's a good reference to have in your back pocket: http://get-spscripts.com/2011/08/diagnose-missingwebpart-and.html